# media queries not working for medium range

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm trying to change my website's body padding depending on the screen size, but the medium range does not work. The website still uses the body padding of the default mobile size. I have tried lowering the min-width from 768px to 767px or lower to see if that will change anything but it didn't. I cannot see what is wrong with the syntax. Have I missed something? Thank you.

```
body{
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 900px;    
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991){
    body{
        padding-bottom: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 500px;    
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    body{
        padding-bottom: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;    
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px){
/*more codes here....... */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be max-width: 991**px**

Also, your last query with "more codes..." can override your previous settings. What are they? if you set those properties here, you literally saying "Ok, apply these when the screen is larger than 768px". This is within your previous range and will be overridden.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. Can't believe it was such a silly mistake and I couldn't see it! (I took out the codes for the last query because it had no body padding related codes, but just thought I should leave that section in in case the ordering of the queries may affect the padding somehow.)

Comment: Happy to hear that. It happens to us everyday :)